# Границы для UI объектов в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

У меня есть Canvas. На нем есть некое поле Field и в нем объект Aim. Aim должен двигаться с определенной скоростью и "отскакивать" от границ Field. Как это сделать?

Вот мои попытки:

```
    public GameObject Aim;

    public Transform MaxX;
    float maxX;                    
    public Transform MaxY;
    float maxY;                   
    public Transform MinX;
    float minX;                    
    public Transform MinY;
    float minY;           //Это все "грани"


    void Start()
    {
        maxX = MaxX.transform.position.x;
        maxY = MaxY.transform.position.y;
        minX = MinX.transform.position.x;
        minY = MinY.transform.position.y;
        Debug.Log($"{maxX} {maxY} {minX} {minY}");
    }
    void Update()
    {
        Move();
    }

    public float Speed;
    void Move()
    {
        Aim.transform.Translate(Aim.transform.up*Speed);

        Debug.Log((Vector2)Aim.transform.position);

        float x = Aim.transform.position.x;
        if (x > maxX)
        {
            Rotate(60);
        }
        else if (x < minX)
        {
            Rotate(60);
        }

        float y = Aim.transform.position.y;
        if (y > maxX)
        {
            Rotate(60);
        }
        else if (y < minX)
        {
            Rotate(60);
        }
    }

    //Вращаем и, тем самым, отскакиваем от грани
    void Rotate(float angle)
    {
        Debug.Log("A");
        Aim.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, angle));
    }
```

Все объекты - `MaxX`, `MaxY`, `MinX`, `MinY`, `Aim` - находятся в Field

Я думал еще добавить коллайдеры, и делать это через OnCollision, но не думаю что это хорошая идея.

В Unity есть куча инструментов для работы с миром. Но как быть, если вся игра - это часть UI?

Comment: Если вся игра - это часть UI, то у вас все печально с архитектурой. Ни в коем случае canvas не должен быть источников игровых событий, его задача - рисовать что-то, опираясь на входные данные.

Comment: Допустим я сделаю это не через UI. Будут ли все размеры сопоставляться с размером экрана?

Comment: + Я не ставил цель сделать архитектуру. Ее просто нет. Ведь это просто программа которую я сделаю за 1 день и благополучно забуду. Тренировка

Comment: Тренируетесь стрелять себе в ногу? Нельзя делать игры через UI, только если вы не хотите получить ужасную оптимизацию и миллиард проблем в придачу.

Comment: Будет ли там что-то "сопоставляться с размерами экрана" - зависит от того, что и как вы запрограммируете.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, я тебя понимаю, звучит тупо, НО дьявол в деталях. Тут всё зависит от того, что ты считаешь `игрой` =D `2048` для тебя игра? Или `текстовые rpg`?

Comment: А что мешает сделать все то же самое через 2д квады? Тут в скорости почти не выиграть, но зачем учиться забивать гвозди с помощью микроскопов?

Comment: 99.9%, что у него `Canvas` не `override`. Это даже не настоящий UI, по сути 2d сцена.

Comment: @Yaroslav не понял, что вы имеете в виду

Comment: ААА. Ясно, посмотрел историю. Он уже спрашивал про  `ScreenToWorldPos` (я-же и отвечал, там где ты про -Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f) спрашивал). У него видимо вообще ничего не вышло, разобраться не может, вот и пустился во все тяжкие. Это просто паника.

Comment: Тогда у меня все получилось (кстати спасибо). И я уже реализовал все не через UI. @Yaroslav У меня 99.9% "настоящий UI").

Comment: Класс. Молодец!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Описанная вами задача решается не `инструментами Unity`, а весьма банальным кодом, без физики. Не `transform.Translate`, а просто `localPosition += MoveVec`. При столкновении с вертикальными стенками менять `x = -x` и соответственно `y = -y` горизонтальными у `MoveVec`. Вот и всё. И никаких `Rotate`.

П.C. не паникуйте и разберитесь с устройством `Canvas` и его взаимодействием с сценой и камерой. Как и написал коллега, игра на UI это стрельба себе в ногу, причём из `BFG`, если только вы не делаете текстовую рпг/квест или 2048.